# Error while permanent deleting soft deleted blob through rest API

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage, sas-token, http-status-code-409

Please help with error PermanentDeleteNotSupportedOnRootBlob

I generated SAStoken for BLOB with all permissions including Delete & Permanent Delete

While making API call using below blog
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob

request url: 
"https://[SAS URL]&deletetype=permanent"

Getting 409 error as "PermanentDeleteNotSupportedOnRootBlob"
[image: responeerror]

x-ms-delete-snapshots in the header is "include"

Storage Account - 'Permanent Delete soft deleted blobs' option is enabled
[image]

Google does not return anything for PermanentDeleteNotSupportedOnRootBlob

Also tried with both Signing method as Account key & User delegation key and got same error

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

To permanently delete blob , ***`their snapshot must also be soft deleted`***
For that Make sure to enable versioning for blobs while creating.

[image]

If already created, you can enable version from data protection configuration.

[image]

With

```
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob?sp=r&st=2023-01-27T12:43:35Z&se=2023-01-27T20:43:35Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=xxxx%3D&deletetype=permanent
```

The blob can be deleted successfully

> **Note**:
>
> 1. Make sure the versionId is given correctly.
> 2. For already existing blob, disable soft delete  , undelete the blobs then enable all the above mentioned properties and delete again.

Otherwise one may come across 409 error.

[image]

**Reference**: [Delete Blob (REST API) -permanent-delete Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob#permanent-delete)

Comment: The option enable versioning for blobs is disabled and unchekced

Comment: In that case , while creating the blobs, make sure it is checked and deleted.